# How to schedule notification

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have a database that I query from to check if the date on there is equals to today's date. Is there a way I can run this PHP script without visiting this page to check if there is any date that is equals to the todays date and send FCM notification? Below is example of what am looking at:

```
<?php
$todaydate = date("Y-m-d");

$query = "select * from TABLE where date = $todaydate";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

...sending FCM notification      

}

?>
```

I know cronjob can do this but don't know how to use on to achieve this.

Comment: You know that this code is broken right? You should be using `NOW()` or `CURDATE()` in SQL

Comment: I didn't use CURDATE() because the timestamp on the SQL server is a different timezone to what I want. The major thing I need here is how this script running periodically without visiting

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the script (for example) every 12 hours.

You can either do this with the Linux command `crontab -e` for the currently logged-in user or you can edit `/etc/crontab` to run the script as a specific user.

With `crontab -e` your line would look like this:

`0 */12 * * * php /path/to/script.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

As I said, in `/etc/crontab` you can specify a specific user. It would look like this:

`0 */12 * * * username php /path/to/script.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

`username` can be something like www-data. Just make sure the specified user has read/execute permissions on the script's file.

`>/dev/null 2>&1` means that the output of the command is muted. You could also write the output into a file. There are also [crontab-generators](https://crontab-generator.org/).

Comment: please where will I add this? In my PHP code? I know this can be added on cPanel under cron job but I want to know how to implement this in my PHP code. Also, do I just need to call this once?

Comment: Also, how can I cancel this later?